# Complex queries, code organization and reusability in this situation?

Tags: model-view-controller, logic, reusability, organization, business-logic

It's a good practice to store the queries and business logic into the models for reusability. How do you deal with complex and full of joins queries, that are only used once in a single method?

I wanna hear your opinion because for me it makes no sense writing them on the models, since they will never be reused. I can end with a model polluted of a dozen of complex queries, making it painful to locate the good methods I can reuse.

What do you do on such case?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make multiple `Partial` class of your model.

You could have files organized like this :

- Basic operations (Create, Read single, Update, Delete, read list, ...)
- Data import logic (lets say you can import data from csv files)
- Data export logic (lets say you need to export to file)
- Business logic calculations on data

Usually, every file would depend on the "basic operations" one.

It's easy to reuse logics (without all the ++ if not needed), quickly organized and simple to use!